# Docker COPY index.html throws error in laravel project

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci-runner

**My Docker file contents:**

FROM nginx:1.18 COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html

**Gitlab Runner** log error message:
Step 2/2 : COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat index.html: file does not exist

Setup: It is *laravel app*. So no index.html file exists…

I have no idea how to proceed…

Thx!

Comment: If you don't have an `index.html` file, why do you have `COPY index.html` in your dockerfile? Just remove that line if you don't need it.

Comment: Thx syntec it worked!! I've just started w Docker and thought this COPY was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by **sytech** I simply needed to delete COPY line.

Because, in my case, I don't need to copy anything. Line was taken from tutorial of setting Gitlab runner.